# Targeting or removing text and images in Wordpress posts

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which displays the post's content using

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

there are images and text in the content which all get outputted in < p > tags

I want to style the margins/padding of the images and text differently. I can target the images but when I apply styles to the text, they affect the images as well.

The only options I can think of are using - margins (but that will cause problems later) and putting all text in block quotes but that will remove that functionality for future use.

can i 'pull out' the images and/or text out of the_content and display them another way?

HTML - currently

```
<div class="row">   
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- /row -->
```

Comment: This will (at some point in the future) be solvable with CSS4, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/4383432

Until then you might be bound to negative margins or something which I can´t just think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways:
My prefered one is the follow:
Let's say that you have a div with a css class (i.e.: content wrapper)
So it will look like this:

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    My amazing conent <img src="amazing.jpg"/> <p>testing paragraph</p>
</div>
```

So in this example you can use simple css selectors to make any change that you want for the elements under contentWrapper i.e.:

```
.contentWrapper img, .contentWrapper p{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Another - but much dirtier way is using regex to replace some tags.
It's not a good practice at all, so I don't thing there is a point of an example.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in my situation since its Wordpress. All the content is put on the page with the_content and all put in <p> tags

Comment: To prevent it from being output, you can use Output Control Functions and `ob_get_contents()` etc. to capture the output and then modify as you please. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Yes you are right - but you can wrap inside the template the place which holds the content itself - this will be the easier way from my experience.

Comment: are you referring to doing in the post editor in wordpress admin?

Comment: This is one option or you can change the template file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Basically two sane ways to go about this:

1. Modify the existing CSS and tune it to target both the elements and the classes more precisely. That's the easier way.
2. Capture the output of `the_content();` into a variable and then use `preg_replace()` etc. to modify the content. Or use a proper DOM parser in PHP to do the same. More work here.
3. (Use Javascript to modify the DOM after it's loaded. Less elegant approach.)

Comment: I'm not super versed in how it is all done, but your second suggestion seems the best choice (I can't target the actually text just the <p> tag, so it's already as specified as I can)  are there any resources that could explain that more thoroughly?

Comment: More on `preg_replace` or DOM parsers? ... and also, couldn't you just modify your WordPress HTML template files instead of doing this post-process, which is a bit hackish?

Comment: I am creating a theme, I am bringing in the content/images with just the line  <?php the_content(); ?> It puts all the content and images in each image and paragraph in <p> tags. I don't really know how to 'take apart' the content php. I have gotten code using preg_match to pull out the block quote

Comment: Looking at `the_content()`, which is a wrapper for `get_the_content()`, which uses give globals and in itself has nothing about wrapping stuff in tags... Um. WP templating may or may not be a pretty world... Have you simply tried canceling out margins in images with something like `.row img { margin: 0; }` ? I'd look further into what you can do with precise CSS without having to modify the DOM on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` to pull the images, remove the `<p>` tags and replace them with something else.

```
function filter_content_images($content) {
    return preg_replace('/<p>\\s*?(<a .*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', '<div class="content-image">\1</div>', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_content_images');
```

This will remove them and replace with  which you can then mini